# Why is the "Add Another Answer" button labelled "Answer This Question"?

Tags: discussion, design

If you've already answered a question the answer box disappears and is replaced by a button that on other sites is labelled "Add Another Answer":

[image]

The image above is from Stack Overflow but it could be Super User, Webmasters, Gaming or any of the other sites I've checked.

But here on The Workplace it's labelled "Answer This Question":

[image]

(It's also like this on Software Engineering).

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this comes up is because we have a lower threshold for a question to have "too many" answers than other sites and the question had more answers than that threshold. The same is true on Software Engineering. If I'd checked a question where I was the only answerer (or one of two) I would have seen the "Add Another Answer" button.

If you click the "Answer This Question" button you get the same dialog that everyone gets asking if you're sure that you really want to answer:

[image]

So this check overrides the "you've already answered this question" check and changes the functionality of the button accordingly.

Comment: This lower answer threshold, in turn, is an [unintended consequence](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2931/325) of stronger policies about comment visibility.

Comment: Interesting trivia: while the page will update in the background that new answers were submitted, you do *not* get a "Are you sure you want to answer" pop-up if you haven't reloaded the page since they appeared so that's tied solely to that type of button.